# Порядок операций инкрементирования и декрементирования

Tags: javascript, алгоритм, инкремент

В каком порядке в данном выражении выполняются операции? Было бы очень хорошо, если бы расписали поэтапно.

```
i = 1; 
a = i++ * ++i + ++i - i--
```

Почему ответ 3? В ходе курса читал про порядок использования инкремента и декремента, но не могу получить ответ - почему результат в данном выражении 3.

Подсказывали, что постфиксный инкремент после вычисления выражения срабатывает, но саму логику не смогли объяснить, возможно хоть кто-нибудь подскажет.

Я явно допускаю где-то фундаментальную ошибку, т.к. если я сажусь записывать смотря на правила, у меня выходит примерно - 1*2+2-1=3, но когда я это показал знакомому,  он парировал тем, что должно быть - 1*2+4-4, и что после 1*2 срабатывает первый инкремент, но я не могу понять, в каком порядке и почему в его решении фигурирует 4-4.

Comment: Возьмите ручку и распишите происходящие здесь операции друг за другом.

Comment: А самое главное, этого совершенно не нужно знать. Такой код просто не нужно писать.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence#Table

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В данном случае операции будут выполняться строго слева направо.

По пунктам:

1. `i++` - в качестве значения будет `1`, значение `i` - `2`
2. `++i` - в качестве значения будет `3`, значение `i` - `3`
3. `++i` - в качестве значения будет `4`, значение `i` - `4`
4. `i--` - в качестве значения будет `4`, значение `i` - `3`

---

В итоге получим:

```
1 * 3 + 4 - 4 = 3
```